# Where are screen lock configuration settings located?

Tags: lock-screen

Could you please point me to the place where Ubuntu 11.10 keeps its screen lock settings?

Using Unity 3D. Screen lock does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Under 'System Settings' -> 'Screen' (on versions prior to 16.04):

[image]

Comment: This has changed / does not exist as of Ubuntu-Mate 16.04

Comment: @Frank question is about Unity desktop anyway